# How to disable "Apply" Button in PowerBI Slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created a few PowerBI reports, but since yesterday every Slice visual object I create comes now with an "Apply" bottom.

[image: apply bottom in slice]

How can I remove / disable it? I couldn't found any guide to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the setting in Options as below:

[image]